# Do we need another repo for each entity?

Tags: domain-driven-design

For example take an order entity. It's obvious that order lines don't exist without order. So we have to get them with the help of OrderRepository(throw an order entity). Ok. But what about other things that are loosely coupled with order? Should the customer info be available only from CustomerRepo and bank requisites of the seller available from BankRequisitesRepo, etc.? If it is correct, we should pass all these repositories to our Create Factory method I think.

Comment: Did you forget your question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  In general, each major entity (aggregate root in domain driven design terminology) should have their own repositories.  Child entities *like order lines) will generally not need one.

And yes.  Define each repository as a service then inject them where needed.

You can even design things such that there is no direct coupling between Order and Customer in terms of an actual database link.  This in turn allows customers and orders to live in completely independent databases.  Which may or may not be useful for your applications.

Comment: "Child entities *like order lines) will generally not need one", they should never have one you mean, otherwise that would compromise aggregates consistency.

Comment: My favorite James Bond movie: "Never Say Never".

Comment: Well, it's up to you if you want to compromise the integrity of your data, but there's no way to ensure data integrity if you allow reaching an AR's boundary without informing it. ARs are transactionnal and consistency boundaries. If you find yourself having to reach into aggregate internals without going through the root, then your model is wrong, unless the child entity is another AR, obviously.

Answer (score 0):

You correctly understood that aggregate roots's (AR) child entities shall not have their own repository, unless they are themselves AR's. Having repositories for non-ARs would leave your invariants unprotected.

However you must also understand that entities should usually not be clustered together for convenience or just because the business states that *some entity* has one or many *some other entity*.

I strongly recommend that you read [Effective Aggregate Design](http://dddcommunity.org/library/vernon_2011/) by Vaughn Vernon and this other [blog post](https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=926) that Vaughn kindly wrote for a question I asked.

One of the aggregate design rule of thumb stated in Effective Aggregate Design is that you should usually reference other aggregates by **identity** only.

Therefore, you greatly reduce the number of AR instances needed in other AR's creationnal process since `new Order(customer, ...)` could become `new Order(customerId, ...)`.

If you still find the need to query other AR's in one AR's creationnal process, then there's nothing wrong in injecting repositories as dependencies, but you should not depend on more than you need (e.g. let the client resolve the real dependencies and pass them directly rather than passing in a strategy allowing to resolve a dependency).